# Optimizing a 3 table join query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, performance, slow-log, query-performance

```
SELECT job.id_job, job.fk_company, job.fk_user, job.fk_job_category, 
job.fk_job_type, job.fk_place, job.job_identifier, job.external_job_id, job.title,
job.short_description, job.status, job.expires_at, job.nb_vacancies, 
job.featured_rank, job.created_at, job.updated_at, job.deleted_at, job.slug, 
COUNT(fk_job) AS `application_count` 
FROM `job` 
INNER JOIN `company` ON (job.fk_company=company.id_company) 
LEFT JOIN `job_application` ON (job.id_job=job_application.fk_job) 
WHERE job.deleted_at IS NULL  
GROUP BY job.id_job 
ORDER BY job.id_job DESC 
LIMIT 50
```

This query takes quite a while, although all of the fields that we use on the `JOIN`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` statements are either indexed, or declared as `foreign key` or `primary key`.

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref                        | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | company         | index | PRIMARY              | company_I_2          | 4       | NULL                       | 3244 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | job             | ref   | job_FI_1             | job_FI_1             | 4       | intjobs.company.id_company |    3 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | job_application | ref   | job_application_FI_2 | job_application_FI_2 | 4       | intjobs.job.id_job         |    1 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`SHOW CREATE TABLE job;`

```
CREATE TABLE `job` (
  `id_job` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_company` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fk_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fk_job_category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fk_job_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fk_place` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_identifier` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_job_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `short_description` text,
  `status` enum('new','active_expiration_reminded','active','inactive','expired') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'new',
  `expires_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `nb_vacancies` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `featured_rank` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_job`),
  UNIQUE KEY `job_U_1` (`job_identifier`),
  UNIQUE KEY `job_slug` (`slug`),
  KEY `job_FI_1` (`fk_company`),
  KEY `job_FI_2` (`fk_user`),
  KEY `job_FI_3` (`fk_job_category`),
  KEY `job_FI_4` (`fk_job_type`),
  KEY `job_FI_6` (`fk_place`),
  KEY `job_FI_5` (`fk_place`),
  CONSTRAINT `job_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_company`) REFERENCES `company` (`id_company`),
  CONSTRAINT `job_FK_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_user`) REFERENCES `user` (`id_user`),
  CONSTRAINT `job_FK_3` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_job_category`) REFERENCES `job_category` (`id_job_category`),
  CONSTRAINT `job_FK_4` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_job_type`) REFERENCES `job_type` (`id_job_type`),
  CONSTRAINT `job_FK_5` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_place`) REFERENCES `place` (`id_place`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27630 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

`SHOW CREATE TABLE company;`

```
    CREATE TABLE `company` (
      `id_company` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `fk_place` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `fk_industry` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `fk_modified_by_user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `featured_rank` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `slug` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id_company`),
      UNIQUE KEY `company_slug` (`slug`),
      KEY `company_I_1` (`name`),
```

`SHOW CREATE TABLE job_application;`

```
CREATE TABLE `job_application` (
  `id_job_application` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fk_job` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('new','application_sent','approval_pending','in_call','invalid','jobseeker_notified','improvement_pending','read_pending','application_read','read_pending_reminded','manual_interaction_pending') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'new',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_job_application`),
  KEY `job_application_FI_1` (`fk_user`),
  KEY `job_application_FI_2` (`fk_job`),
  CONSTRAINT `job_application_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_user`) REFERENCES `user` (`id_user`),
  CONSTRAINT `job_application_FK_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_job`) REFERENCES `job` (`id_job`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf
```

MySql Version:

```
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.22                       |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| version                 | 5.6.22-log                   |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: What does `explain select` of the query says ? Please add that into the question.

Comment: You can combine the `GROUP BY job.id_job ORDER BY job.id_job DESC` to `GROUP BY job.id_job DESC `. It will be more efficient (although this syntax is going to be deprecated).

Comment: Also: do you have an index on `(deleted_at)` or on `(deleted_at, id_job)`? It would be good if you added the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE job;` (and for the other table as well).

Comment: You need an index on `job.deleted_at` , `alter table job add index deleted_at_idx(deleted_at)`

Comment: Another thing. Why the join to `company`? It's not used anywhere. Is `job.fk_company` nullable?

Comment: Its joining to company check the 2nd row table is `job` and `ref` is `company`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty it is not used in the SELECT list or anywhere else though. Seems useless.

Comment: The company id is selected to have an easy access to to the company model via Propel, I suspect.

Comment: Sidenote: The `KEY job_FI_6` index is identical to the `job_FI_5` one. You can remove one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three points that the query can be improved:

- remove the join to `company`. The joining condition is through a non-nullable foreign key, so it should always be true.
- change the `GROUP BY x ORDER BY x DESC` to: `GROUP BY x DESC`. This will avoid the extra sorts. Note that the syntax is under deprecation, so you may need to change it back in a future mysql upgrade.
- add an index on `(deleted_at, id_job)`. This is essential for this query. In general, an index on a flag (true/false) column or one that has few distinct values is often useless. But the `deleted_at` column is a timestamp so the index can be useful in other queries as well. This query has the extra `ORDER BY / LIMIT`, so the 2-column index can be used effectively.

The query rewritten:

```
SELECT job.id_job, job.fk_company, job.fk_user, job.fk_job_category, 
  job.fk_job_type, job.fk_place, job.job_identifier, job.external_job_id, job.title,
  job.short_description, job.status, job.expires_at, job.nb_vacancies, 
  job.featured_rank, job.created_at, job.updated_at, job.deleted_at, job.slug, 
  COUNT(fk_job) AS application_count 
FROM job
  LEFT JOIN job_application ON job.id_job = job_application.fk_job 
WHERE job.deleted_at IS NULL  
GROUP BY job.id_job DESC 
LIMIT 50 ;
```

You could also use this version, which forces using the index and avoids the `GROUP BY` in the main query (groups by in the inline subquery which will be run only for 50 values):

```
SELECT job.id_job, job.fk_company, job.fk_user, job.fk_job_category, 
  job.fk_job_type, job.fk_place, job.job_identifier, job.external_job_id, job.title,
  job.short_description, job.status, job.expires_at, job.nb_vacancies, 
  job.featured_rank, job.created_at, job.updated_at, job.deleted_at, job.slug, 
  ( SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM job_application AS ja
    WHERE j.id_job = ja.fk_job  
  ) AS application_count 
FROM 
  ( SELECT id_job
    FROM job
    WHERE deleted_at IS NULL  
    ORDER BY id_job DESC 
    LIMIT 50
  ) AS j
  JOIN job ON job.id_job = j.id_job  
ORDER BY j.id_job DESC  ;
```

Comment: Used the easiest solution of creating the index, query time dropped dramatically.
I guess it is a good practice to index deleted_at wherever it is used as a filter for the query.

Comment: Great. (dramatically=?, just curious). It would be good if you added the version of MySQL in the question. And thnx for the prompt answers to comments and question updates. Not all users get that point, and their question stalls.

Comment: On staging: first query: 16 sec, second query: 5.5 sec (with SQL_NO_CACHE for some reason as well).
with the new index: 0.01 sec.

Comment: Posted mysql version